# I can read from a plist but fail to read from another one

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I created two plist file named information.plist and data.plist in my Supporting Files, and I add both them to Copy Bundle Resource.

I use the code below to  read data from the plist.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask , YES );
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary* dictPlist = [ [ NSMutableDictionary alloc ] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

and try to show data from the plist:

```
NSMutableDictionary *data1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSLog(@"%@", data1);
```

I get the data from information.plist but get "null" from data.plist.

Did I miss something?

Thanks for your helping!

Comment: The two plist files are in the app bundle, not the Documents folder. Unless, of course, you have other code that copied the files.

Comment: But why the information.plist worked?
And how to copied this file to Documents folder?

Comment: Where are you reading it from? The bundle or Documents?

Comment: When I publish this app, I should read plist from Document? Am I correct?

Comment: No. The plist files in Supporting Files while be part of your app's bundle, not the Documents folder.

Comment: OK，So I should read from the bundle.
But yesterday , I just read from document, and I archive the app and share with my tester. It works ....

Comment: The only way you can read a file from Documents folder is if you wrote code to first copy or create the file in the Documents folder. A freshly installed app will NOT have any files in the Documents folder.

Comment: I read data from plist like that before today:

    `NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask , YES );
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/information.plist",documentsDirectory ];
    NSDictionary *dictFromPlist = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSLog(@"this is read from plist %@",[dictFromPlist objectForKey: @"user_cityName"]);`

Comment: Double check file presence in your documents directory as well. Also, check if there is some code that copies file in documents directory. File copied in supported files gets baked in app during sandboxing and are available for access only from bundle. You can try exploding your .app file to see the file presence.

Comment: Finally, I know that if you want write into plist, you should save the plist file to the CocumentDirectory. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Path of plist from bundle
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];

// Since your plist's root is a dictionary else you should form NSArray from contents of plist
NSDictionary *dataPlist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

**Explanation : Your plists are in application bundle and not inside Documents directory which is why you are not getting them.**

Comment: If you are putting your PLIST in supporting files then you must read it from bundle as I mentioned in my code.

Comment: `    NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSMutableDictionary* dictPlist = [ [ NSMutableDictionary alloc ] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];


    NSLog(@"---------------this is the only way:%@",dictPlist);
`
NULL again.
I am test with my iphone, does it matter?

Comment: Please be advised to check the file name including casing. It must be `data.plist` in your `Supporting Files` folder. As I suggested above, double check the present of `data.plist` after  application is compiled inside your `.app` file.

Comment: Thanks for your help, means a lot to me.

Comment: Always happy to help. Did it fix your issue?

Comment: I know that if you want write into plist, you should save the plist file to the DocumentDirectory. The plist file in bundle is readonly.